# Having trouble using Capybara and Selenium to find an svg tag on a page

Tags: selenium, svg, capybara

I had a test case like this:

```
  scenario "there should be an SVG tag" do
    ...
    page.find("svg")
  end
```

For some reason, Capybara could not find the svg tag even though when I looked in the page's source, the tag was there (and also visually).

I was only able to get it to find the SVG tag after I did something like:

```
  scenario "there should be an SVG tag" do
    ...
    page.find("#layers *[xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']")
  end
```

(Note, the svg is within the "layers" ID).

Does anyone have any ideas? I use Selenium as the driver.

Comment: Does anyone know if Selenium have problems with svg tag?

Comment: Was this an XHTML page, or HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is an issue with Firefox's built in xpath evaluator.

Using FireBug, I was able to verify that the call that Selenium uses:

```
document.evaluate("//svg", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue
```

doesn't return any elements, whereas

```
document.evaluate("//div", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue
```

returns the first div on the page.

There may be some namespacing issues that could get FireFox to return svg elements. For now I've just looked for elements with my svg xmlns attribute.

Comment: It turns out that ".//svg" does not execute the same as ".//*[name()='svg']". I believe it has to do with namespacing issues.

Comment: The comment made by shawn42 fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution which enables the use of CSS selectors:

```
scenario "there should be an SVG tag" do
    ...
    Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page.body).css('svg')
end
```

Strange and annoying that it doesn't work out the box using page.find(), though.

Comment: what happens when it can't find 'svg'? Will the test fail?