# Capybara CSS or xpath to find an element based on two conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, capybara

I'm trying to use the find method to find an element based on the following:

id starts with ship_
and the data-coordinates attribute does not equal 0,0,0.

The css for the first part i have easily enough:
`find('path[id^="ship_"]')`

but i'm not sure how add the second condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Capybara supports CSS3, you could try:

```
path[id^="ship_"]:not([data-coordinates="0,0,0"]);
```

Comment: That worked sort of. It looks like firefox xpath has issues with SVG tags (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433825/having-trouble-using-capybara-and-selenium-to-find-an-svg-tag-on-a-page), so i removed the context of the path. Knowing the page I'm testing, nothing else will start with ship_ :). If it does become a problem, i can adjust it later.